# linked list - circular

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
typedef struct hwnd *HWND;
struct hwnd{
 int id;
 HWND siblings;
 HWND next;
 HWND prev;
};
int main()
{
 HWND siblings = malloc(sizeof(struct hwnd));
 HWND handle = malloc(sizeof(struct hwnd));
 for(siblings=handle->siblings;siblings&&siblings!=siblings->next;siblings=handle->siblings)
 {
  handle->siblings = siblings->next;
  handle->siblings->prev = siblings->prev;
  siblings->prev->next = handle->siblings;
 }
 return 0;
}
```

This code the condition of the for loop throws a deepcheck error as REDUNDANT_CONDITION_AFTER_FIRST_ITERATION. This error occurs when a condition is always true from the second iteration.

Please help me fix this problem.

**EDIT:**

Sorry as my question was not correct.The handle->siblings and handle->next and handle->prev are allocated with numbers somewhere in the program. I could not understand why they need to do a check like this siblings && siblings != siblings->next . All i could understand from this is they are checking that siblings -> next contains some address and siblings not equal to NULL by doing siblings&&siblings. Please correct me if i'm wrong . As manos said the priority is != and then && so it has to execute correctly without any deepcheck errors even though  we miss to put the brackets.

Please help me find what might be the root cause of the problem.

Comment: As the loop in your example won't run at all (`siblings` will always be `NULL`) I have a hard time knowing where you get the error from.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this `siblings&&siblings` is not what you want... Also I am trying to follow your code but I am a bit confused. What you really want to do?

Comment: I guess he/she is trying to do siblings && (siblings!=siblings->next)

Comment: Yes the priority is !=, &&, || so without the parenthesis is the same with your guess. But still can not figure out what he/she tries to do.